# What does under license mean?

Tags: licensing, trademark

[Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html#license) says:

> NOTE: GIT is a trademark of Software Freedom Conservancy and my use of
>   "Gitolite" is under license.

What does **under license** mean here? Does it mean **Software Freedom Conservancy** gives permission to use `Git` phrase inside `Gitolite`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the SFC doesn't allow the usage of the term "git" for third-party products unless they have their permisison.

From the [Git Trademark Policy, 2.3 Prohibited usages of the Marks](https://git-scm.com/trademark):

> In addition, you may not use any of the Marks as a syllable in a new word or as part of a portmanteau (e.g., "Gitalicious", "Gitpedia") used as a mark for a third-party product or service without Conservancy's written permission. For the avoidance of doubt, this provision applies even to third-party marks that use the Marks as a syllable or as part of a portmanteau to refer to a product or service's use of Git code.

Comment: Thanks. Can SFC only prevent Git usage in Programming industry? And what happens someone comes with something like `gitgit` that is not about version controlling say email service? Can SFC still prevent `git` usage in `gitgit`?

Comment: @JohnBernard those are new questions; perhaps you should ask them as such.  But in general, to answer these questions, you can read up on trademark protection.